# why is the ajax loader blurred?

Tags: css

Loader has a strange blurry patchy color. Original loader doesn't look like the one attached. Please see attachment and the below code. [![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
#acp-overlay
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: black;
    -moz-opacity: 0.3;
    opacity:.3;
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    z-index: 10000;
}

    #ajaxcartpro-progress{
        border: none;
        position: fixed;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: transparent;
        z-index: 999999;
        color: black;
        max-width: 200px;
        /*position:absolute;*/
        /*top: expression(parseInt(document.documentElement.scrollTop, 10) +window.ACPTop+ "px");*/
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a GIF image to create the animation, have a look at [CSS3 keyframe animations](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/an-introduction-to-css3-keyframe-animations/) and use a PNG sprite.

EDIT: I think the [Walsh's article](http://davidwalsh.name/firefox-animation) describes it quite easily.

To start with, of course you need a container like `<div class="loading"></div>`

Then, using CSS, you set its background-image to a sprite containing the animation in steps. Basically, what occurs here, is that you show only a **part** of the background each refresh and thus create the animation. The browser does nothing but pushes the background-position (or other attributes too) with time like this:

```
@keyframes loadinganim {  
    0% {background-position: -6864px 0; } # starting position depending on the sprite image
    100% {background-position: 0 0;} # where should the animation end
}

.loading {
  background-image: url(images/loadingSprite.png); # path to the sprite
  animation: loadinganim 3.75s steps(44) infinite; # what's the animation called, how often it should refresh, how many steps, and for how long it should last
  # ... other attributes
}
```

This isn't supported by older browsers, however, so you need to provide a fallback (like a GIF image with a background). You might also need to prefix `animation` attribute to make it work in browsers like Safari:

```
.loading {
  animation: # ...
  -webkit-animation: # ..
  # ... other attributes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's a GIF image.  GIF images don't support alpha transparency, so it's antialiased against a white background.  But you're overlaying it on top of a background that isn't white, so you see the gray pixels that are supposed to blend in with the white.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. It is a gif image but the same image is working well on a other site. any how to fix this?